AssertionError when the serializer does not find an object in Django Login
I'm creating an app in django with custom registration and login that behave like forms, but when I log in with wrong credentials, the program returns an AssertionError.
.
views.py
...
def post(self, request):

    serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():

    email = serializer.validated_data['email']
    password = serializer.validated_data['password']

    user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

    if user:
            
        login(request, user)

        return redirect('/')

    else:

        return Response({'erro': 'user nao encontrado'})

serializers.py
class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True,
        style={'input_type': 'password'})

    class Meta:

        model = Profile
        fields = ['email', 'password']

    def validate(self, attrs):

        email = attrs.get('email')
        password = attrs.get('password')

        if email and password:

            user = authenticate(email=email,
                password=password)

            if not user:

                raise serializers.ValidationError('O usuário não existe')


        attrs['user'] = user

        return attrs

The error in question:
AssertionError at /accounts/login/
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `StreamingHttpResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`

I've already tried a try and except, as well as adding a Response if the user doesn't exist, but still, nothing works.

So what AssertionError? Share the full traceback.

@willeM_VanOnsem, the error in question: ```AssertionError at /accounts/login/
Expected a Response, HttpResponse or StreamingHttpResponse to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>````

A view must always return a response. In your case there is one case where your view returns Nothing (None).
It's when serializer is not valid. I assuming that in your code all is well indented and you just make a mistake there on StackOverflow.
def post(self, request):
    serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():

        email = serializer.validated_data['email']
        password = serializer.validated_data['password']

        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user:
        
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('/')

        else:

            return Response({'erro': 'user nao encontrado'})
    # When serializer.is_valid() return False, we are here, and the view ends by returning None. Django immediately raise an Assertion Error. You must add a else close here.
    else:
        # Return a response here.



i think you must fix indentation
def post(self, request):

    serializer = LoginSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():

        email = serializer.validated_data['email']
        password = serializer.validated_data['password']

        user = authenticate(email=email, password=password)

        if user:
        
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('/')

        else:

            return Response({'erro': 'user nao encontrado'})


The problem is not the indentation: ( it was just an error formatting the code in SO.

@danielcerk is it pass valid process?
